# Can not Change Variables in Release Pipeline

Tags: variables, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to change some variables in the release pipelines. But after I change and click the save button, I see a white screen and the change is not applied.

Sometimes I also take "An undefined error occurred while attempting to connect to the server. Status code 0: ." error

I tried to refresh the page but it did not work.